# How can I use interactive pre-commit hooks with magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

Is it possible to configure magit so that it spawns an interactive shell for pre-commit hooks that require user input?

For an example of one such pre-commit hook, take a look at [git-confirm](https://github.com/pimterry/git-confirm).

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have found the solution, for git-confirm, I think Magit can handle it, check `magit-process-yes-or-no-prompt-regexp` for details. If you have some prompts could not be handled by Magit, try `magit-process-prompt-functions`.

More information at https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3845